# multiple navigation host base layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to move my application to a single activity app as recomended by google.
for this I created a few nav host and nav graphs for each section of my app,
 one nav host fragment for the authentication flow which would keep the company logo at the top while navigating beetween screens for login, sign up, 2fa... so for this I created a nav host fragment with a container and the view logo.
 Also one nav host fragment for the section in my app that uses the bottom navigation view, so there is a bottom nav host fragment with all screens sharing the bottom nav bar.
there is another flow that is not suposed to have the bottom nav bar, so I created a third nav host with just the container this time.

all those 3 flows are scoped to the main activity that is the main navigation host, this is just the activity layout with the navigation container.

the problem is the only navigation host that keeps a view other than the container is the main navigation.
when navigating to the bottom nav host fragment, the bottom nav bar is no there, but if I move the bottom navigation view to the main activity the nav bar shows up but it is there for ever, even in the auth flow, then I would have to remove manualy this bar in each and every fragment in my app that not use the bottom nav.

the question is how to have a baselayout for a nav host? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way I found out to fix this problem is not to work with single activity application.
Now I have a simple host activity for app entry( main activity) with no base layout, the login flow which keeps a base layout is another acitivity host but with its own views as well as the part of the app that uses bottom navigation, there is a acitivity host just for the bottom navigation. also in the navigation graph, the action has to be from the fragment to the new activity, if the destination is a nested graph the base layout for the previous activity is kept...
I could fix this adding more activities and handling flows with activities instead of nested flows... this works fine but I cant share view models in some parts of my applicatino wich is one down side for this approach.